# Delay in loading jsp page?

Tags: performance, jsp, servlets

I am having a login jsp page, after entering all the credentials and while clicking on the login button, I am redirecting it to a servlet which does all the login processing and then dispatching to a another jsp page. Iam finding delay in opening the jsp page. What can be the problem...? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is far too vague. Please post the code code to your Servlet so people can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry i have no liberty to post code...:(

Answer (score 0):

If you are not precompiling the JSPs before deploying, your container will do that on the fly. This is probably the delay you are seeing.